# Visual Studio marked all files as changed

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

Ok, i don't know what happened, but today i opened a solution in my work, got latest version from TFS, a coworker made a lot of changes, that's Ok. But  Visual Studio (2015) marked all the files from all projects with changes, and if I compare them to the last version, no changes at all, probably a white space or ending lines problem. But why every file is marked with changes? I heard that anti virus software can make date changes, but that never happened to all files before.

Now i have to look the files to locate the ones that i actually changed, include them and undo the rest, or something happened that i can reverse this? I tried refresh the Team Explorer window and close and opening the solution again and the changes were still there.

I May have check out a single file by accident (miss click), but that was on a single file and I cancelled it.

Just a Tip: I found that you can compare entire folders for changes in files, in that method of comparing, Visual Studio shows correctly the files that i have actually changed, managed to undo all files in this way.

Comment: Did you or your coworker ever do a baseless merge or **rename** root folder/branch which will cause all files list in pending changes?

Comment: Checking the changeset, apparently we didn't rename anything and we don't work with branches, we get the solution from TFS, make changes and then check them in. In the last changeset a coworker checked in a lot of packages and updates of older frameworks, but we did this in the past without this problem. It's probably something in my computer or a configuration, because only my solution that occurred. I undid the changes and will keep an eye if this happens again, thanks.

Comment: If only occurs on your machine, sounds like something related TFS or VS cache or some source control related configuration. Glad to hear the issue fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time if the same issue occurs a work around is to undo your pending changes. When you get the confirmation dialog choose "**No to all**". Only your real pending changes should be left. This works when you only have changes to files, make sure when selecting the files, you do NOT select newly added files as they will be removed from pending changes.

Compare entire folders for changes in files is also worked, however you still need to **manually** select files to undo them.

Comment: Yeah, i ended up undoing them manually comparing entire folders, luckily i didn't have many files that i actually changed. I'll keep an eye in this, thanks.

Comment: Be carefull with this solution. It worked for me but only with modified files. The added files was not recognized like added. I have to added it manualy.

Comment: This is the best solution. Unbelievably, there seems to be no more straightforward way to filter out changed files only. The recursive "Compare" finds all the changed files, but frustratingly, you can't do anything with the results.

Comment: Undo -> sort by change type -> Shift (or ctrl) to highlight all actual changes -> spacebar to un-select them -> perform undo. Added files must be done manually